# How can I get more than one document from mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb, express

I have Button component which is generated 16 times, it has the localstate(reactjs) but I need to make it kind of global by using connection with mongoDB so I have to get 16 documents from one collection for every Button and I don't know what I do bad.. The best I could achieve is either generating the whole collection 16 times or getting one document 16 times.. How can I get another documents? Like 1st,2nd,3rd...16th. Please help

The code:

```
router.get('/:name', (res, req) => {
const name = req.params.name

console.log('name', name);

 Buttons.find({ name: name})
.then(buttons => res.json(buttons))
.catch(err => res.status(402).send({message: 'error while fetching'})
);
});
```

and the code of function :

```
  async function getButtons(name) {
try {
const response = await axios.get(`api/buttons/${name}`);
 return response, console.log(response);
catch (error) {
console.log(error)
}
}

 console.log(getButtons());
```

Comment: please explain in simple way what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: Oh, sorry. I want to get unique records for each one component. I have documents in mongoDB like: name: button1,name: button2,name: button3. I want to get it and assign it later to the components

Comment: you are using mongoose Right ?

Comment: @Goteii Buttons.findOne() will give you only one document so if you want to get all buttons you have to call Buttons.find() it will return all the buttons then you can handle it on client.

Comment: @PrakashKarena yes I use mongoose

Comment: @MuhammadJunaidAziz Yes I know. I thought it will work like it will get one document for each one component which I wanted to do.. But it doesnt. If i use Buttons.find() it gives me 16 documents for 1 component.. So basically 16x16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your name as param from your req

```
router.get('/:name', (res, req) => {

 const name = req.params.name;

  console.log('name',name); // check you are getting name or not ?

 // findOne will find your one document as per your name and return your document is better to use then find 

 Buttons.findOne({ name : name })  
.then(buttons => res.json(buttons))
.catch(err=> res.status(402).send({message : 'error while fetching recored' }))

});
```

for front end

```
const getButtons = async (name) => {

    let RESULT;

     axios.get('api/buttons/${name}')
      .then( response => { RESULT = response.data } )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    console.log('RESULT',RESULT);

    return RESULT;

}


 console.log('data',getButtons('button1'));
```

now you can call this function with name getButtons(your_button_name) and you will get your buttons response as per passed name.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206546/discussion-on-answer-by-prakash-karena-how-can-i-get-more-than-one-document-from).